# Distribution of color changes in a black/white ball sequence

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions

while this is research-related, I think it is a rather basic problem/puzzle so I thought I post it here.

I came across a combinatorical problem which can be phrased in the following way. Given $n$ balls $k$ of which are black and $n-k$ of which are white. What is the probability over all possible sequences of these balls to have exactly $c$ color changes?

The expected number of changes is easy. This appears sometimes in a stochastics course as an exercise. Let $X_i$ be a binary random variable which is 1 iff ball $i$ and ball $i+1$ have different color. The number of color changes is $C=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i$. Since the $X_i$ are identically distributed with $P[X_i=1]=\frac{2k(n-k)}{n(n-1)}$ we have $E[C] = (n-1)E[X_i] = 2k(n-k)/n$.

However, they are not independent since $C\leq \min\{2k,n-1\}$ (otherwise $C$ would be simply binomially distributed).

So is there some way to compute the distribution for $C$? Upper bounds would also be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For odd $c$, there are $\frac{c+1}2$ runs of white and black balls each. We can start with either white or black, which yields a factor of $2$, and then we can distribute the $k$ black balls over the $\frac{c+1}2$ non-empty runs in $\binom{k-1}{\frac{c-1}2}$ ways and the $n-k$ white balls over the $\frac c2$ non-empty runs in $\binom{n-k-1}{\frac{c-1}2}$ ways, so the number of sequences with $c$ colour changes for odd $c$ is

$$
2\binom{k-1}{\frac{c-1}2}\binom{n-k-1}{\frac{c-1}2}\;.
$$

For even $c$, there can be either $\frac c2$ runs of white balls and $\frac c2+1$ runs of black balls or vice versa, so the number of sequences with $c$ colour changes for even $c$ is

$$
\binom{k-1}{\frac c2+1}\binom{n-k-1}{\frac c2}+\binom{k-1}{\frac c2}\binom{n-k-1}{\frac c2+1}\;.
$$